# Trouble with widget size and adding new widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, widget, pyqt5

I ran into an issue tonight that involves resizing a QTextBox in a QGridLayout. The code is mostly self-explanatory. I set the QTextBox to span 10 cells down in my init_ui. I have a window size of 500x500.

```
def init_ui(self):
    self.message_body = QTextEdit()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.message_body, 2, 0, 9, 7)
    self.show()
```

And then in a later method, changeSize, I am successfully able to change the size of QTextEdit. From this method I call the next method to load titles that will appear below the 445x280 QTextEdit. Loading these titles calls for new widgets to be added to the layout. Which is apparently a problem. I don't know if this is poor styling or not. Should all of the widgets be added in init? Either way when

```
self.layout.addWidget(lbl_title, 10, i)
```

runs. I lose my resized QTextEdit. Even if I follow it with another resize function.

Here are the two methods implicated

```
def changeSize(self):
    self.message_body.resize(445,280)
    self.loadTitles()

def loadTitles(self):
    titles = Movie.title_library
    for i, my_title in enumerate(titles):
        lbl_title = QLabel(my_title)
    ## This is the line that refreshes the size to span 10x8 units    
        self.layout.addWidget(lbl_title, 10, i)    
    self.message_body.resize(445,280)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I needed to remove the message body widget before reinstating it. The code looked like

```
self.layout.removeWidget(self.message_body) 
self.layout.addWidget(self.message_body,2,0,4,7)
```